# IOS/iPhone - Button launches Camera or Voice Memo

Tags: iphone, ios, video, voice

I just need a code when I click on the button it closes my app and launches the Camera or Voice Memo app.

Code for both would be helpful.

Code I was using:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"videos:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to launch Camera.app, in part because of the fact that it has no URL scheme, and in whole because Apple expects you to implement your own camera, and makes it very easy to do so.  Take a look at the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) documentation for more info.

It's also not possible to launch Voice Memos.app because it has no known URL scheme.

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for a the URL scheme for these items but couldn't find it.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Absolutely.  Next time, know that the one thing that really cheeses off an SO-ite is asking outright for code.

Comment: @MichaelD If Coda's answer helped you, please accept it.  There's a check mark to the left of his answer--click it to accept the answer.  Thanks for helping keep the site clean!